# Add className by setState in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I assign an `className="active"` to a loop with `setState`

```
this.state = {clicked: true}
...
{i.rate_plans.map((j,index) => {
  return(
    <div key={index}>
      <h2 onClick= {() => this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})}>{j.name}</h2>
      <div className=${this.state.clicked ? '' : 'active'}>...</div>
    </div>
  )
})}
```

This adds the class to all items in the loop. How can I add to the item clicked, not the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep an object which keeps track of all your `rate_plans` that have been clicked.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    rate_plans: [{ name: "test" }, { name: "test2" }],
    clicked_rate_plans: {}
  };

  onClick = plan => {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      const clicked_rate_plans = { ...previousState.clicked_rate_plans };
      clicked_rate_plans[plan.name] = !clicked_rate_plans[plan.name];
      return { clicked_rate_plans };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.rate_plans.map((j, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <h2 onClick={() => this.onClick(j)}>
                {j.name} {this.state.clicked_rate_plans[j.name] && " clicked"}
              </h2>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Tholle. I am trying to integrate your solution but hitting some hurdles - here is the entire code https://codesandbox.io/s/n050n8kqkp. If you don't mind having a look. Adding the solution you have above is producing an `undefined` error. Cheers.

Comment: As a learner first I thought adding `checked` property to rate_plan individuals but with this method we don't need to mutate the data itself and we can clearly see in our state which piece of data is `checked` easily. Loved it @Tholle, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Works as intended and makes more sense now. Would you know what is causing `Uncaught TypeError: onOutsideClick is not a function
    at OutsideClickHandler.onMouseUp`?

Comment: @devserkan Glad you liked it! It's a very powerful technique.

Comment: @Darren I'm not sure. Might be a good idea to open a separate question with a reproducible example if you don't find the issue.

Comment: No worries - appeared since edit but likely caused elsewhere. Thank you again for your help. Above and beyond an answer I had expected and better yet, I learnt something.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the problem. You are just using one variable to store which element is clicked. And if you'll click even one element, it'll add `active` class to all of elements as they're based on just one variable. What you've to is to have an array and store the clicked state based on index of element in array. Then it'll work fine. I've created a sandbox for you.
Here's 
***([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/43z701jnkw))***

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort here. This will surely be an asset for others to come but I have chosen to use an answer posted by Tholle.

Comment: No problem at all. You found the answer, which is most important thing ;-)